# Why is the basin of an asymptotically stable solution to a differential equation an open set?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, limits

Why is the basin of an asymptotically stable solution to a differential equation an open set?
The basin is defined as the set off all points s.t. their limit at $t = \infty$ is equal to some solution $x_0$.

This seems pretty intutive; if I'm at a point that will reach the basin, moving in any direction by a little shouldn't affect my limit. How do I say this formally? Any help would be appreciated!